# How to use multiple variable from tibble in an user-defined function?

Tags: r, dplyr, user-defined-functions, tibble

I have created a tibble consisting of 6 columns containing 6 different variables that will be input for a user defined function. I am new to r, and I don't know how to connect the tibble with user defined function. Please help.

I have replaced the complex user defined function with simple `user_defined_function` for the sake of discussion.
`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
rgb_val <- seq(from=0, to=255, by=10)
rgb_grid <- expand_grid(r1 = rgb_val, g1 = rgb_val, b1 = rgb_val,
                        r2 = rgb_val, g2 = rgb_val, b3 = rgb_val)

user_defined_function <- function(x) {
  x[,1] + x[,2] + x[,3] + x[,4] + x[,5] + x[,6]
}

rgb_grid %>% mutate(new_cols = user_defined_function ())
```

I want the results of the `user_defined_function` to be added as new column to the tibble `rgb_grid`. However, if what I have tried, unsuprisingly, throws an error.

Comment: Does your example really have to use 300 million rows? Also generally when using function in dplyr, you need to pass values via parameters. Functions won't "inherit" the data without actually passing it. You could use `rgb_grid %>% mutate(new_cols = user_defined_function (across(r1:b3)))` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are passing the whole dataframe to the function, you can't use mutate. Rather, just pass the whole dataframe to the function and add that to your data.frame.

(by the way I changed your `rgb_val` sequence to `to = 20` otherwise the dataframe is huge -- are you trying to destroy my computer haha).

Here's an approach with the tidyverse:

```
rgb_grid %>% 
  bind_cols(setNames(user_defined_function(.), "new_col"))

# A tibble: 729 × 7
      r1    g1    b1    r2    g2    b3 new_col
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0       0
 2     0     0     0     0     0    10      10
 3     0     0     0     0     0    20      20
 4     0     0     0     0    10     0      10
 5     0     0     0     0    10    10      20
 6     0     0     0     0    10    20      30
 7     0     0     0     0    20     0      20
 8     0     0     0     0    20    10      30
 9     0     0     0     0    20    20      40
10     0     0     0    10     0     0      10
# … with 719 more rows
```

Or with Base R

```
new_col <- user_defined_function(rgb_grid) 
cbind(rgb_grid, new_col)
```

Comment: Thank you! I could work with this. Do you have any idea how I can deal with my output, which is also multiple variables? I was thinking `unnest()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function exactly how you have constructed it as follows:

```
rgb_grid %>% mutate(new_cols = user_defined_function(rgb_grid)[,1])
```

Note that because your function takes in a dataframe and returns a one-column dataframe, I've used `[,1]` to select that one column as a vector. A more typical pattern however, for your user-defined function would be to have multiple parameters, say one for each column that will be used in the function.

Comment: This `mutate` doesn't really use the data that's piped in. This wouldn't work if you also had a `group_by` before the `mutate()` since you are using the original variable name in the function call. So just be careful about that.

Comment: I agree, and thanks. Was just giving an example of how one could use the function as written, and added a note as to why this is non-typical pattern, and not one any of us would probably recommend. I appreciate the comment.